# JMS provider URL for jboss in-vm destination

Tags: jms, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

Running app on EPA 7 with log4j2.  We have an appender that writes to a JMS queue.
I got it working for remote connection as below:

```
    <JMS name="HIFAuditAppender"
         destinationBindingName="jms/queue/HIFAuditQueue"
         factoryBindingName="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" 
         providerURL="http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080"
         username="hcmuser"
         password="gators123="
         factoryName="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" />
```

However, the JMS producer and MDB are running in the same JVM.  I want to use the jboss in-vm connector, but have not been able to determine what the providerURL should be set to.

Answer (score 0):

The providerURL will be same i.e `http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080`. You need to use in-vm connection factory i.e `/ConnectionFactory` which uses in-vm connector and used to produce/consume messages locally.

Comment: the context factory name I have does not work in this case.  I also tried, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory"  no luck on that either.